# Slider on matshow for 3rd dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to visualize a 3D space and would like to navigate the Z dimension by a simple slidebar. Currently I just iteratively show each stack in the Z plane by destroying the current image and then plotting the next. How can I edit the below simple example to allow for a slidebar to go back and forth in the Z direction?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 

if __name__=="__main__":
    nx = 100 
    ny = 100 
    nz = 10

    xs = np.linspace( -1, 1, nx )
    ys = np.linspace( -1, 1, ny )
    zs = np.linspace( -1, 1, nz )

    A = np.zeros( (nx,ny,nz) )

    for ix in range(nx):
        x = xs[ix]
        for iy in range(ny):
            y = ys[iy]
            for iz in range(nz):
                z = zs[iz]
                A[ix,iy,iz] = x*np.sin(z*x) + np.cos(z*y) + np.cos(z)

    for iz in range(nz):
        plt.matshow( A[:,:,iz] )
        plt.show()
```

Comment: If the linked question does not solve this problem, you'd need to be more specific about your needs.

Comment: I have the solution, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest open please

Comment: @eyllanesc In how far would the solution be different to those answers to other questions?